# How to delete nested subdocuments automatically when i delete the document that contains them in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Every time i try to delete a document in mongoose the subdocuments nested inside it stay is there any trick to get rid of them ?.

Comment: what you have tried can you upload?

Comment: Yes read about and use mongoose middleware.